# Clarification Needed in a proof of Dolbeault Isomorphism related to Riemann Surface

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, sheaf-cohomology, complex-manifolds

I am reading Dolbeault Isomorphism from Raghavan Narasimhan's "Compact Riemann Surfaces". I am facing some difficulties to understand some portions. If someone can explain these that will be very helpful.

$\bullet$ Let $X$ be the riemann surface and $\mathbf{E}$ is a holomorphic vector bundle over $X$. The author defines $\mathcal{A}_E ^{0,1}(W):=C_E ^{\infty}(W) \otimes_{C^{\infty}(W)} \mathcal{A}^{0,1}(W)$ where $W\subseteq X$ open, $\mathcal{A}^{0,1} (W)=$ space of $1$-forms on $W$ of type $(0,1)$ [i.e. locally of the form $b \hspace{0.3ex}d\bar{z}$] and $C_E ^{\infty}(W)=$ the space of $C^{\infty}$ sections of $E$ over $W$. I know what is a tensor product, but I can't understand what the space $\mathcal{A}_E ^{0,1}(W)$ really is. Is the tensor necessary just to have forms with coefficients in smooth functions? Please explain.

$\bullet$ I think this is kind of related to my first question. I need some explanations how $ 0\rightarrow \mathbf{E}\rightarrow \mathbf{E^\infty}\rightarrow \mathcal{A}_E ^{0,1}(W)\rightarrow 0$ forms a short exact sequence of sheaves. Here $\mathbf{E}^\infty$ is the sheaf with $\mathbf{E}^\infty (W)=C_E ^\infty (W)$ for $W\subseteq X$ open.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sections of $A^{0,1}_E$ don't simply consist of $(1,0)$-forms with coefficients in smooth functions, but really of $(1,0)$-forms with coefficients in smooth sections of $E$. This is different than simply $A^{0,1}$. You didn't define what was $E^{\infty}$ also.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet   sorry.. added the definition. And do you mean $(0,1)$ form?

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet thanks for your comment would be please clarify a little more... may be with an example...

Comment: Yes I meant $(0,1)$ form sorry. Do you understand difference between smooth functions on $X$ and smooth sections of a vector bundle $E$ on $X$ ? The difference is exactly the same.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet yeah I understood that. Actually I was trying to visualize $A^{0,1}_E$ also some kind of set of forms... there the idea of coefficients in smooth sections of $\mathbf{E}$ doesn't really fit into... can you explain the second problem a bit may be...

Comment: $A^{(0,1)}_E$ is the sheaf of $C^{\infty}$ section of the vector bundle $E \otimes \Omega^1 $. For the second point, I guess the map is $f \mapsto \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}fdz$ in local coordinates. Then the map is surjective (as a map of sheaves) because locally any $1$-form can be written like that and the kernel is exactly when $ \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}f = 0$ i.e when the section is holomorphic.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet what is $\Omega^1$ here ?

Comment: Sorry that was a very bad notation, I meant the vector bundle $T^*X$. What is written $\Omega^1$ is usually the sheaf of holomorphic $1$-forms (which I didn't mean, sorry for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discussion above solves it. All credit goes to Nicolas Hemelsoet.